# Allow user to edit specific user with meta key using map_meta_cap

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

Is there a way "hook" or custom code to allow user with custom role "abc" to edit and remove another users with custom role "xyz" by using map_meta_cap ?

Thanks

Comment: No, there is no built-in way to allow a user to edit only a subset of users. Managing users includes capabilities that apply to all users - `edit_users`, `list_users`, `promote_users`, `create_users`, `add_users`, `delete_users`. If you just need to grant them access to edit and delete users across the board, using `add_cap` and assigning whichever of these capabilities you want them to access will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I think its possible, I have wrote a code in functions.php in the theme and its working fine. If there someone could make it better :D
We have a custom meta for each user and that could be done using ACF. Admin only can set that meta to the user (beauticians).

I have 2 custom roles salonowner, and beauticians.
salonowner have access to edit, list users. 
We have a post type "Listing" and salonowner can create a post there. Lets call it Salon1.
Admin only can assign beauticians to Salon1 by using ACF "meta" and I have create Relationshop field.. here its called list_for_user.

Here we create the 2 new custom roles:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'create_custom_roles' );
function create_custom_roles() {
    add_role( 'salonowner', 'salonowner');
    add_role( 'beauticians', 'beauticians');
}
```

Here we assign edit and list users for salonowner role:

```
add_action('admin_init','add_role_caps',999);
function add_role_caps() {
    $salonowner = get_role('salonowner');
    $salonowner->add_cap('edit_users');
    $salonowner->add_cap('list_users');
}
```

With this custom code we can deny salonowner from editing any other users and let him only edit the user that have same meta for their Listing "Salon1".

```
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'custom_map_meta_cap', 10,4);
function map_meta_cap( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ){
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_current_screen' ) )
        return;
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if($screen->base == 'users' || $screen->base == 'user-edit') {

        $user_meta = get_userdata($user_id); 
        $user_roles = $user_meta->roles; 
        if($user_roles){
            if (in_array("salonowner", $user_roles)) {

                if( isset($args[0]) ){
                    $edit_user_id = $args[0];
                }

                $listing_ids = get_user_meta( $edit_user_id, 'list_for_user', true);
                if($listing_ids){
                $arr = get_current_user_posts_can_edit();
                    foreach ($listing_ids as $key => $listing_id) {
                        if (in_array($listing_id, $arr )){
                            return $caps;
                        }else{
                            $caps = 'do_not_allow';
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    // Don't allow for edit all other users 
                    $user = get_userdata( $edit_user_id );
                    if ( $user ) {
                       $caps = 'do_not_allow';
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $caps;

}
```

Here the function to get all posts for the current user to check if he can edit the user that assigned for it:

```
function get_current_user_posts_can_edit(){
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'listing',
        'post_status'       => 'publish',           
        'author'            =>  $current_user_id,
    ));  
    $post_ids = array();
    foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
        $post_ids[] = $post->ID;
    } 
    return $post_ids;
  }
```